# Can one compute the coherence matrix in Python for a multivariate signal with out resorting to loops?

Tags: python, signal-processing

Given two signal vectors, x and y, the command

```
f, Cxy = signal.coherence(Signal[:,i],Signal[:,j], fs)
```

available in the scipy toolbox, yields the coherence values between signals x and y at the corresponding frequencies listed in f.

Is there a built-in python command for creating the coherence matrix for a multivariate signal, or must I resort to using loops? In other words, if X is my signal matrix of size N-by-C, where N is the number of time points and C is the number of channels, is there a built-in command to compute f,S, where f is a list of frequencies and S has size C-by-C-by-len(f) with the property

S[i,j,k] denotes the coherence between channels i and j at the kth frequency in f?

I seem to recall such a command for Matlab (mscohere?), but I can't find one in Python. I'd rather not resort to nested loops if possible.

Comment: `Is there a built-in python command` - did you look through all the documentation?

Comment: I can't seem to find anything in the Scipy documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.coherence.html to indicate there is.

Answer (score 0):

Over three years late, but just in case anyone else comes across this question...

You can compute a coherence connectivity matrix of shape `(len(f), C, C)` (where `C` is the number of channels or signals and `len(f)` is the number of frequencies) for multivariate signals by altering the shape of the signals array by adding a new axis.

Use the `numpy.newaxis` functionality to add new axes to your signals array at offset positions:

```
    f, Cxy = signal.coherence(x=Signal[:, :, np.newaxis], y=Signal[:, np.newaxis, :], fs=fs, axis=0)
```

This should return an array assigned to variable `Cxy` of shape `(len(f), C, C)`. I haven't checked, but I imagine calculating the coherence connectivity matrix this way would be faster than using loops, as you're only calling the `spicy.signal.coherence` function once as opposed to `C x C` times.